# HTML Table for Column Description?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, jquery, classic-experience

Is it possible to insert a small HTML table for the column descriptions. I have a bunch of acronyms that I use the description to have the definition of what they represent, and instead of having them all in a column making the form take up more room, I would like to have rows and columns.

Or since it is possible to insert scripts into New/Edit list forms. Can you insert html with JavaScript? For example, not have a description by default, but populate one?

**EDIT**:

So I have tried the following. The field description I am trying to populate is the following (I did not provide a description in the column information in list settings).

[image]

Here is the table that I am trying to append under the MondayStatus along with a working fiddle.

```
var $table = $('<table style="text-align: center;"/>');
$table.append( '<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'P = Present' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'LA = Leave Annual' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'H = Holiday' + '</td></tr>'+
'<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'JD = Jury Duty' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'OL = Other Leave' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'SL = Sick Leave' + '</td></tr>' + 
'<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'ML = Military Leave' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'NR = Not Reported' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'O = Off-site' + '</td></tr>' + 
'<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'TAD = Temp. Additional Duty' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'TLV = Transitional Leave' + '</td><td style="border: 1px solid black;">' + 'TRNG = Training' + '</td></tr>');
$("select[title^='Monday Status']").closest('td').append($table);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/rja36xg7/36/

Comment: Are you using classic experience list forms or modern experience list forms?

Comment: Classic, but can use either

Comment: You can append HTML table using JS/[jQuery append() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) in Script editor/content editor web part in classic experience.

Comment: If the descriptions all have the same class name, how would you do this individually?

Comment: If you do not have a description by default, there is no `span` element created for description. So no need to worry about class name of description. check my answer given below for simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using classic experience, you can append HTML table (or any element you want) using JS/[jQuery append() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) in Script editor/content editor web part in classic experience.

**Example**:

```
$("input[title^='Content Amount']").closest('td').append('<span class="ms-metadata">Custom Description for Content Amount field</span>')
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. You do not need to add SharePoint default description for this field.
2. `Content Amount` in above code is column display name.

Similarly you can append HTML table to `td` element.

---

**Update**:

I just tried your code & it is working fine for me:

[image]

Try writing your code in below format:

```
function runAfterEverythingElse(){
    // Add your code here
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
```

Make sure you are using correct selector for your HTML element.

Comment: Please see the edit to my post. Nothing gets appended to the field description